# How to perform addition of date which taken from database in PHP5?

Tags: php, mysql

actually I save date in database in varchar format.
firstly I retrieve date from databae & store it into $date. 
now i want to perform addition of 5 days with $date1.

when i search on internet i got this code :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+5 days"));
```

now can you tell me how I insert $date1 value to this code for get expected result.

Comment: "actually i save date in database in varchar format" -- for what reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with strtotime you could to something like this:

```
<?php

$date = "2010-04-01";

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+5 days", strtotime($date))); // 2010-04-06
```

The first `strtotime($date)` call converts the string into an timestamp integer, the secound call takes that integer and adds 5 days to it. Then `date` formats it back into a string

---

On a sidenote:

There is not really a need to save a date as a varchar since mysql (which i guess is what you are using from the tag) will also work with "DATETIME" fields for you. E.g. `SELECT DATETIMEFIELD FROM table` will return '2010-01-01 00:00:00' or a "DATE" field will return "2010-01-01", both are `strtotime` parseable :)

Answer (score 2):

I've already added my vote to edorian's answer since that answers your question directly.

However, you can actually add the 5 days at the time you query from the database using `DATE_ADD`

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( your_date_column, INTERVAL 5 DAY ) AS newDate
```

On another note, why not use the `DATE` format for your date column rather than `VARCHAR`?

Comment: +1 For mentioning [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Comment: +1 from me too. Nice addition, may save some lines where it's easier & clearer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Or a simple +

```
SELECT ( your_date_column + INTERVAL 5 DAY ) AS newDate;
```

There is no need for something strange like DATE_ADD() when you have a + and -

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days', strtotime($date1)));
```

hope this will do ;)